# How to add a group of scatter plots to another group of scatter plots in excel 2016

Tags: excel

I have a block of data for scatter plots - about 500 rows, single column of X values and 10 columns of Y values. I have a second block of data for scatter plots with 200 rows, single column of X values and as high as 20 columns of Y values. It's easy to plot separate scatter plots for each block of data. Is there a simpler way to combine both scatter plots into one than manually selecting X and Y data 20 times over. Both groups of scatter plots have similar X and Y ranges so that's not going to be an issue. Example images of each scatter group is in the links below. Appreciate the tips.

[Example Scatter Group 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP2LE.png)
[Example Scatter Group 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QYMY.png)

EDIT: PowerQuery Approach

@QHarr Thank you for suggesting the approach. Unfortunately, when I try and **Merge** the tables on the first column, it doesn't work as expected. Maybe I've not uderstood the steps properly but I think it's because my x-axis value (the common column 1) are not exactly the same on both tables. I.e the Simulation data has somewhat ordered coordinate values like 0.001, 0.002, 0.003... and so on whereas the experimental data is more random 0.00121, 0.00189, 0.0022 and so on. This might be why I see the "The selection has matched 1 out of the first 460 rows" on the **Merge** window.
[Merge Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6azO.png)

Comment: And scatter plots are generally about correlation between 2 variables so do you really mean to add these together?

Comment: @QHarr Well, Excel calls them scatter plots i.e. I used the "Insert Scatter or Bubble Chart" option. The first group is experimental data at different times and the second group is the same data from numerical simulation. The x axis is coordinate location - the experimental data is more spatially resolved hence the additional rows. Each column on each group refers to a discrete time. I basically want to compare the simulation with the experimental.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment until now as you edited it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

So the best I have come up with, without code, is to:

1. Create two tables from the distinct ranges and add them via powerquery (via data from table) as connection only. With a cell selected in the table to add via powerquery > Powerquery tab (Excel 2016)/Data tab (2016) > From table
2. Then create a new query > merge query and merge the two tables you just created. Join on column 1 from each (the x axis) and use
3. Make sure when creating the merge query to i) connection only load ii) add to data model iii)delete the additional column 1 and rename any columns if wanted
4. Create a pivot insert > pivottable > external connection > choose connection > merge query
5. Arrange data in subsequent pivot as required
6. Create pivotchart > line chart > choose a chart style with markers > format each data series with Line = No line.
7. Format chart in any other desired way, e.g. hide buttons on chart

Bit annoying to set-up but then will update when you add new data and refresh the query and pivottable. You can do this by pressing the Data > Refresh All icon.

Step 1

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 1 contd]

Step 2:

[image: step2 contd]

Step 3

[image: Remove column]

Step 4

[image: Step 4]

Step 6

[image: Step 6]

Output (Step 7):

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

In excel, this is the simplest way I have found to combine two already created scatter plots into a single plot:

1. Select one plot
2. Press Control-C, or Right click on the plot and select Copy
3. Select the second plot
4. Press Control-V, or Right click on the plot and select Paste

Excel will copy all Data Series from the first plot into the second.  The only problem is that it will copy all formatting from the first to the second plot as well, such as axis titles and ranges. The copied data series will keep the same colors, markers, etc., but the ones in the destination plot will have formatting applied from the copied plot. See the figures below:
[image: figures demonstrating series data merging]

Chart 3 is the result of copying Chart 2 and pasting into Chart 1.  Note the axis range and series colors/formats were kept from Chart 2. The series data is now part of Chart 3, but none of the formatting from Chart 1 was kept.

I haven't yet found a way to preserve data series formatting when doing this. Would appreciate any comments to help with that.

EDIT: After selecting the destination Chart, you can select Paste Special from the ribbon, and it will give you options of All, Formats, Formulas.  So you can choose either to copy the format over, or copy the data series over, but thus far I see no option to merge the data and preserve formatting of both sets.